# Remote workstation management

Tags: system, user-management, multiple-workstations

Some of my family members asked me to install Ubuntu on their laptops (because I just refuse to do anything windows related anymore), but helping them over the phone can be a pain.

Is there some kind of spacewalk/landscape alternative just for workstation management?

Things like Foreman, Salt, Ansible, ... all seem overkill, and don't seem to support dynamic ip's anyway.

Comment: You have 2 problems - dynamic ip and client. Use a service such as dyndns and automate update of ip address or set a static ip. Then use ssh or FreeNX

Comment: Indeed. Those are the problems I would like to solve automatically.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you need?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like a remote desktop client/server? So you can log into their desktop and do things remotely from your computer, while letting them watch (& hopefully learn)?

Possible options include:

- [remmina](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/remmina) -    remote desktop client for GNOME desktop environment
- [vinagre](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/vinagre) - remote desktop client for the GNOME Desktop [universe]
- [vino](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/vino) - VNC server for GNOME
- [gnome-rdp](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/gnome-rdp) - remote desktop client for GNOME [universe]

There are security concerns with running these over the internet:

- [Ubuntu's help on VNC](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC) suggests using **ssh** and looks like a great setup:

  > Although VNC has some optional security features, you should not run VNC directly over an untrusted network like the Internet. Instead, you should set an SSH server up as discussed in the [SSH guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH) and configure a VNC server that you can start in so-called once mode. When you have set up your SSH and VNC servers, you can use SSH to log in to your computer over the Internet, start your VNC server, and use [port-forwarding](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VNC#port-forwarding) to securely access the VNC server.
- [Securing Remote Desktop for System Administrators](https://security.berkeley.edu/node/94) (windows-centric but relevant concerns)

Or for a text-only solution you can use plain ssh, but that probably wouldn't be very helpful for any relatives to see what's going on.

Comment: FreeNX is faster and more secure then all of those sugestions. You should also mention ssh as it is not clear a graphical interface is required, and on can run a few apps over ssh -X . You did not address the security of those options over the internet (this is by far one of the most common reasons Ubuntu is cracked) or the problem with a dynamic ip address.

Comment: Not quite. I actually do want an overview page where I can install packages from, and such.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen excellent points, I haven't used remote desktops outside of a local network, but I'll add your comments.

Comment: @skerit your question is quite broad as you have several options. You can install packages over ssh for example. Do you want a desktop (VNC) or web based solution (webmin) ?

Comment: @bodhi.zazen Yes, it's more of a webmin thing I'm looking for. I know it can be done manually, but I just wondered if there's something that already does it all so I don't have to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: well, try webin then ;)